# Problems receiving large amount of data through ruby TCP Socket

Tags: ruby, sockets, tcp

I am sending and receiving JSON data through a TCP socket. It works fine when it is smaller amounts of data, like 200 bytes or so. But when it gets to about 10 KB it only receives part of the data. I have tried all the different TCP socket retrieve data commands I can find (read, gets, gets.chomp, recv) but I cannot find one that will work for all of my tests.

Here is the code I have now:

```
socket = TCPSocket.new '10.11.50.xx', 13338
response = socket.recv(1000000000)
```

I have also tried adding a timeout but I could not get it to work:

```
socket.setsockopt(Socket::SOL_SOCKET, Socket::SO_RCVTIMEO, 1)
```

I am not sure what I am missing. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's [badly documented](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/socket/rdoc/BasicSocket.html#method-i-recv) in the Ruby docs, but I think `TCPSocket#recv` actually just calls the `recv` system call. That one (see `man 2 recv`) reads a number of bytes from the stream that is determined by the kernel, though never more than the application specifies. To receive a larger "message", you will need to call it in a loop.

But there is an easier way: because `TCPSocket` indirectly inherits from the `IO` class, you get [all of its methods](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html) for free, including `IO#read` which does read as many bytes as you specify (if possible).

You wil also need to implement a way to delimit your messages:

- use fixed-length messages
- send the length of the message up front in a (fixed-size) header
- use some kind of terminator, e.g. a NULL byte

Comment: This fixed my issue. I sent the response using a TLV wrapper and was able to use the length to determine how many bytes to read. I used 'TCPSocket#read' instead of 'TCPSocket#recv'. Thank you!