# Ruby TCP Socket does not read the entire input data

Tags: ruby, sockets, tcp, tcpserver

I've implemented a simple tcp server listening on a specific address and port:

```
TCPServer.open(address,port) do |server|
    file = File.open(file_name,"wb")
    while client = server.accept
        while buffer = client.gets()
            puts buffer
            file.write(buffer)
        end
    end
end
```

When through netcat I send short strings or under 4096 bytes it reads them entirely. When the message exceeds the size it is truncated, even after the connection and once the eof is reached.

I tried to implement an alternative to TCPServer:

```
one_hundred_kb = 1024 * 100
Socket.tcp_server_loop(address,port) do |connection|
begin
   file = File.open(file_name,"wb")
   # Read data in chunks of 1 hundred kb or less.
   while data = connection.readpartial(one_hundred_kb) do
       puts data
       file.write(data)
   end
   rescue EOFError
       connection.close unless connect.nil?
   end
end
```

This solution also seems to have the same problem as the previous one.
I found a [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19037879/problems-receiving-large-amount-of-data-through-ruby-tcp-socket)
that might clarify the issue but but I can't change the way the client sends the messages to the server.

Is there a way to change the maximum read size and why the data is truncated and can't be recovered?

**EDIT**

As @Stefan asked me, I highlighted my problem by sending a very large string greater than 4096 bytes (composed of a very long sequence of 1s and with two trailing xxs). On the server side, the final data was truncated and the x's were not displayed.

**EDIT 2**

Analyzing the traffic generated directly by netcat with tcpdump, I noticed that it's actually netcat that cuts the maximum length to 4096 bytes.
So both the Socket and TCPServer classes work fine with the production client. The bug that led me to use netcat to test the differences between the class derived from **the lack of management of the EOF** (managed correctly in the case of the implementation with the Socket class above). This caused the generation of a **corrupted binary**.

Comment: Can you add an example of _sending_ an amount of data that causes your server to have incomplete data?

Comment: @Stefan 
I added an edit in my question.

Comment: I meant a code example, something that I can copy and paste to replicate the problem. (netcat, Ruby, etc)

Answer (score 1):

You just have the false impression that the file were truncated, since you look at its content before it has been closed or flushed.